# How to save data in localStorage with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, local-storage

I'm starting with AngularJS and have my first problem with it.

How can I bind or save username and password in the localStorage? My form is empty after reloading the page or restarting the app.

I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="cy_username" id="cy_username" ng-model="username">
<input type="password" name="cy_password" id="cy_password" ng-model="password">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive icon ion-edit icon-left" ng-click="saveSettings()">Einstellungen
            speichern
        </button>
        <button class="button button-block button-assertive icon ion-trash-b icon-left" ng-click="resetSettings()">
            Einstellungen löschen
        </button>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['LocalStorageModule'])

    .controller('SettingsCtrl', function ($scope, localStorageService) {
        $scope.username = localStorageService.get('username');
        $scope.password = localStorageService.get('password');


        $scope.saveSettings = function () {
            if (localStorageService.isSupported) {
                localStorageService.set('username', $scope.username);
                localStorageService.set('password', $scope.password);
            } else {
                console.error('localStorage is not supported!');
            }
        };

        // doesn't work, nothing happens
        $scope.resetSettings = function () {
            $scope.username = '';
            $scope.password = '';
            localStorageService.clearAll();
        };
    });
```

Comment: isn't it should be `localStorageService.cookie.clearAll`?

Comment: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage#clearall

Comment: What you are wanting to do is a bad idea from a security standpoint. You should NEVER store both the username and password anywhere in your app, especially in localStorage or a cookie. Log the user in, and then store a unique session ID that you can refer to. Those values belong in a database and thoroughly encrypted.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `saveSettings` (and `resetSetitngs`) functions?

Comment: @MBielski: Thanks. Yes, I know. I'm just testing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a really bad practice to store user credentials in localStorage.. 
But I got a [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/qociro/6/edit?html,js,console,output) working for your requirements and it works.. 
Do scroll to bottom for the JS code as I included the library on top of JS

PS: Ignore the js errors and warnings. Those are from the angular-local-storage library

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But why? I can't understand. I added a form tag with ng-submit and changed the button to submit-type. Problem was still there, but after adding ng-controller="SettingsCtrl" it works. But I thought, it is already set in the module?

Comment: You have to put the controller on the DOM (html) element too on which the controller would apply as ng-controller="MyCtrl". That defines the Scope of the controller actually. Without it, the functions and the models won't automatically apply.
So you have to do both: 
1) apply the controller on html
2) define the controller as appModule.controller

Comment: But why works <input ng-model="test"> and {{test}} without applying the controller on html? Sorry for my questions.

Comment: If you don't initiate a controller, angular uses the $rootScope for your application. And if you don't define a model in a controller or at $rootScope, angular creates that model (test in your case) automatically. So using a model isn't an issue but you can't use a function that you didn't define and angular doesn't define functions :) You have to have a controller and the function definition for that.

PS: I'm good with giving answers as long as you Up-Vote them :) 
lol.. jk

Comment: By the way do check the initial examples out at https://angularjs.org/ . I hope that'll make things much clearer to you :)